# How to plot a histogram with strings in anylogic

Tags: anylogic

i have an array with some random sequence
for example : `long[] X = {23,1,4,2,.............,4,2,1,3,..........};`
in data base i have the names for each numbers(names in the image)

[image]

i want to plot a histogram for `(23,4);(1,2);(4,2);(2,3)............`from the sequence in `X[]`.

but I need something like this

[image]

I am not sure how to do it, as the data set only allows the type double, how can I add strings.

```
long[] X = Disassemblysequence.getDisassemblySequence(); //random sequence 

String[] Components = f_Components(); //list of Components from data base

for(int i = 0; i<C; i++){
    String A = Components[(int)(X[i] -1)];
    double EOL = (double)X[i+C];
    String Status = "";
    //double Com = (double) X[i];
    //double S = (double) X[i+C];
    if (EOL == 0){
        Status = "Not Removed";
    }
    else if(EOL == 2){
        Status = "Reuse";
    }
    else if(EOL == 3){
        Status = "Remanufacture";
    }
    else if(EOL == 4){
        Status = "Recycle";
    }
    d_Components.add(A,EOL);
}
```

Comment: Is that the count of each combination that you want to plot?

Comment: no, i have total of 64 double value i want to plot for (X axis : 1st valuse  VS  Y axis : 33rd value) and so on until i finish all the combinations (2 VS 34)...............(32 Vs 64)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that you don't want a histogram per see, since a histogram will calculate some of the values for you, which you already have calculated. Rather you simply need to display them in a bar chart.

You can add bars to a bar chart using standard code see example below

[image]

And here is the output

[image]

If you want to have custom x-axis labels you need to not show the legend and create your own - but this can be a separate question

Comment: sorry Mr.jaco, i dont want to convert from String to double, i want to plot the histogram for double values where this each value have a name "String". when my histogram is plotted i want to see these names insted of numbers

Comment: Ok check my new update